# SQL - Join and Subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 4 tables in my Database

**Bookings**

```
Booking_Id : int, Primary Key
Hotel_No : int, foreign key
Guest_No : int, foreign key
Date_From :  date
Date_To : date
Room_No : int, foreign key
```

**Guest**

```
Guest_No : int, primary key
Name : varchar(30)
Address : varchar(50)
```

**Hotel**

```
Hotel_No :  int, primary key,
Name : varchar(30)
Address : varchar(50)
```

**Room**

```
Room_No : int, primary key
Hotel_No : int primary key, foreign key
Types : char(1)
Price : float
```

**Question:**

I want to display all information from room table on a given hotel. If a Guest is staying in one of the rooms today, i want to display his name, else null.

i've tried several Queries, but none of them solves my problem.

Thanks in advance

edit:

I've tried something similar to

```
select Room.*,Guest.Name 
from Room 
join Booking on Room.Room_No = Booking.Room_No 
join Guest on Guest.Guest_No = Booking.Guest_No
where Booking.Hotel_No = 6 AND cast(Date_From AS DATE) < = cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)
```

When i use this Query:
Select * From Room where Room.Hotel_No = 6

I get this result

[image]

But the result i want is:

[image]

Comment: This does look like a homework problem (hint:  in the real world, money is not stored using `float`).  You should include what you have attempted.

Comment: ^ Haha, spot on, Sir :D

Comment: This is a homework problem :).

Comment: And Kasper, we meet again :D

Comment: haha true :) you previous solution was actually solving another problem.

Comment: Well after 12 hours trying to solve this problem, i think a helping hand is needed. I've put my energy into this assignment and can't seem to figure out how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the solution:

```
select Room.*, Guest.Name from Room 
left join(select * from Booking where Booking.Date_From <= GetDate() 
And Booking.Date_To >= GetDate()) as book on room.Room_No = book.Room_No 
left join Guest on book.Guest_No = Guest.Guest_No where Room.Hotel_No = 6
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Select r.*, g.name
from Room as r
left join Booking as b on r.Room_No = b.Room_No 
left join Guest as g on g.Guest_No = b.Guest_No
left join Hotel as h on h.Hotel_No = b.Hotel_No
where h.Hotel_No = 6 AND b.Date_From <= cast(GETDATE() as date)
```

Comment: the table looks as i want it, but the 'Booking.Hotel_No = 6' is also showing the another hotel numbers. 
I only wants to show the rooms once in that paricular hotel.

Comment: Still the same result. It is showing all the rooms on all the hotels

Comment: you do not need `Hotel_No` in `Book` table, because `Room` linked to `Hotel`, but any way try this update.

Comment: Still not solving the problem

If i use this query i get the expected result: select * from Room where Room.Hotel_No = 6

Comment: The only thing missing is another column that shows the guest name if he lives on the hotel today.

Comment: I tried this solution and work for me, that is strange why is not working with you ? can you try `left outer join` as a latest test ?

Comment: and this: `Select r.*, g.name
from Booking as b
left join Room as r on r.Room_No = b.Room_No 
left join Guest as g on g.Guest_No = b.Guest_No
left join Hotel as h on h.Hotel_No = b.Hotel_No
where h.Hotel_No = 6 AND b.Date_From <= cast(GETDATE() as date)`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT R.*,B.*, G.*
 FROM BOOKING B
RIGHT JOIN ROOM R
ON B.ROOM_NO = R.ROOM_NO 
AND B.HOTEL_NO =R.HOTEL_NO
FULL JOIN GUEST G
ON B.GUEST_NO = G.GUEST_NO
AND B.HOTEL_NO = 6 -- CUSTOMIZE THE HOTEL NUMBER TO YOUR REQUIREMENT
```

Comment: This ain't solving the problem.
Lets say i have 6 rooms in hotel_no = 6
Then i wants to show the 6 rooms once, and with another column call e.g GuestNameAtRoom will display name of the guest if he lives in a room on the current date. If no ones is living in a room, it should display null. I Hope that makes sense

Comment: You are missing some code at the end of the query :)

Comment: Still not solving the problem :/, i still want to display ALL the rooms from the given hotel, and display guest name, if he is living there today else display null.

Comment: By given hotel, do you mean you will specify it explicitly? Is it 6 in your case?

Comment: Trim the column names to the ones you want. I have given all columns to be selected

Comment: No rooms is shown now. I want no matter what, to show the rooms at the hotel. So if there is 6 rooms at the hotel, i want to show 6 records. 1 record per room. The last column should show if there is one guest living in that room today. if there is one, show his name. If there is none, show null. Hope it makes sense now :)

Comment: And i only wants to show the rooms for 1 hotel, not them all.

Comment: Wrongly JOINED the Guest and Booking table which should have been RIGHT JOINED. Check now. If it doesn;t work, i need to see your data

Comment: It stil doesn't work, i've edited my post to clarify my question

Comment: I only got 6 rooms in that hotel so the maximum records the table must display is 6. You query is showing 99 records which is incorrect